# Why does this Applet not working

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint, mouselistener

I've been watching videos on youtube on how to use MouceListeners, and on the video it worked, however on my computer it doesn't. Here is the code
        package Applets;

```
    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

    public class MouseListenerTut 
    extends Applet
    implements MouseListener{


private Graphics GG = null;


private void Init(){
    this.addMouseListener(this);


}

private int Mx;
private int My;


public void paint(Graphics g){


    GG = g.create();

    this.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));

}


public void DrawDot(int x, int y){

    int r = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int g = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 255);

    Color Col = new Color(r,g,b);
    GG.setColor(Col);
    GG.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     Mx = e.getX();
     My = e.getY();

    DrawDot(Mx,My);
}


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}






    }
```

I really don't get why it won't work, it doesn't show any errors, and it seamed to work perfectly for him...

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. What do you mean by 'not working'?

Answer (score 1):

`g.create()` returns a copy of the graphics object, so you are modifying a copy not what is painted. Even if you weren't passing a copy you would be modifying the graphics object after it has already been painted.

You should really modify g inside your `paint()` method, then just call `repaint()` when the mouse is clicked, something like this;

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class MouseListenerTut 
extends Applet
implements MouseListener{

    private void Init(){
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    }

    private int Mx=0, My=0;
    private Color Mc = Color.WHITE;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Mc);
        g.fillOval(Mx, My, 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Mx = e.getX();
        My = e.getY();
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int g = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int b = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Mc = new Color(r,g,b);
            repaint();
    }

    //Spare Listeners
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing to retired graphics. Use a BufferedImage to keep track of all your drawings.

Use this paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Use this mouseClicked method:

```
public void DrawDot(int x, int y)
{
    int r = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int g = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 255);

    Graphics g = buffer.createGraphics();
    Color Col = new Color(r,g,b);
    g.setColor(Col);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    g.dispose();

    repaint(); // make sure you show your edits on screen
}
```

And finally make sure you have a `buffer` object. Put this in your class:

```
 private BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGBA_PRE);
```

Comment: I'm not greatly familiar with `Applet`s, but with a `JFrame` `paint()` is only called when the `JFrame` is moved off and back onscreen or resized. Without calling `repaint()` on mouse click your method may never paint more than the original `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll add to my answer.